# py2app with postgres/psycopg2

Tags: python, psycopg2, py2app

So I'm trying to use py2app for my project. Now I don't get any errors from py2app. It is writing near the end the following:

```
/usr/bin/strip: for architecture x86_64 object: /Users/bogdan/Documents/TVB/tvb-root/gemenos/trunk/dist/run.app/Contents/Frameworks/libgfortran.2.dylib malformed object (load command 3 cmdsize not a multiple of 8)
```

But it build the dist/build folders. But when I try to run my application I get the error:

```
  File "project/core/storage/dao.pyc", line 13, in <module>
  File "sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.pyc", line 263, in create_engine
  File "sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.pyc", line 50, in create
  File "sqlalchemy/engine/url.pyc", line 116, in get_dialect
```

sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not determine dialect for 'postgresql+psycopg2'.
2011-07-12 15:20:06.680 run[4310:10b] run Error

I tried googling around and the only thing related was:

http://osdir.com/ml/sqlalchemy/2011-05/msg00104.html

but I don't really understand that answer nor do I know if it actually helped at all.

Any suggestion?

Regards,
Bogdan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help!!  I just struggled through the same problem.
Found this site: (not in english unfortunately, but it worked for me)
http://bancaldo.altervista.org/2011/07/py2exe-errori-post-freeze/

What I did was to add an include to my .py

For MS SQL

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.base import dialect
```

Or for SQL lite

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.base import dialect
```